# Data Type in SMT solver which supports normal additon, xor, or , and operation simultaneously

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, z3, smt, sat

I am trying to solve some nonlinear equation on boolean variables and at the same time I want to compute the hamming weight (i.e. involve normal addition of boolean variables).

I am using Z3 Smt Sovler & Bitvec to do so, but it seems there is some restriction on the number of monomials that can be passed into an equation.

I am therefore looking for some alternative solution;

Problem:

```
x1,x2,......, x100 = boolean variables
```

I have to solve:

```
x1 + x2 + .... + x100 = 58
```

and some non linear equations.
I have attached a sample code to show the error.

I request you to please help me as I am new to Z3 smt solver.

Code:

```
from z3 import *

N = [BitVec('n%d'%i,7) for i in range(40)]

EQ = [N[0] ^ N[13] ^ N[19] ^ N[35] ^ N[39] ^ N[2]&N[25] ^ N[3]&N[5] ^ N[7]&N[8] ^ N[14]&N[21] ^ N[16]&N[18] ^ N[22]&N[24] ^ N[26]&N[32] ^ N[33]&N[36]&N[37]&N[38] ^ N[10]&N[11]&N[12] ^ N[27]&N[30]&N[31] ==1 ]

print(EQ[0])

Output:
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ^
... ==
...
```

At the same time if I reduce the number of monomials then the it gives the correct expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the pretty-printer limiting how much it prints (to reduce voluminous output), not an internal limitation of z3.

You can raise the limit by adding the following line after `from z3 import *`:

```py
set_option(max_args=10000000, max_lines=1000000, max_depth=10000000, max_visited=1000000)
```

You can tweak the numbers to suit your needs, but the above should be enough for all practical problems of interest. If I add this line to your program, I see as output:

```
n0 ^
n13 ^
n19 ^
n35 ^
n39 ^
n2 & n25 ^
n3 & n5 ^
n7 & n8 ^
n14 & n21 ^
n16 & n18 ^
n22 & n24 ^
n26 & n32 ^
n33 & n36 & n37 & n38 ^
n10 & n11 & n12 ^
n27 & n30 & n31 ==
1
```

which is what you were expecting, I presume.

If you want to see everything in one line, then use the following settings:

```
set_option(max_args=10000000, max_width=1000000, max_lines=1, max_depth=10000000, max_visited=1000000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me. Is there any way to print the equation in horizontal manner rather than vertical? As I have to see large number of equations to analyse.  And one more thing why it takes too much time to print equation in smt solver as compared to SAT solver in sagemath.

Comment: See my updated answer on how to print everything in one line.

Comment: It worked, thanks. One thing left, it takes more than 2-3 minutes to print around 100 complicated equation in SMT while in the sat solver it prints within one second. Any reason for that ?

Comment: Try printing the expression directly: `print(EQ[0].sexpr())`. I'd expect that to be a lot faster, though of course not as pretty. When you have a large formula like this, the time it takes to pretty-print dominates everything else.